# Xcode: show 'Utilities' pane only with .xib file

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

**Can it be done?** There is absolutely no reason why `Utilities` pane should be shown with regular (say, `.h` and `.m`) source files ... so one has to always cycle between hiding/showing the `Utilities` (in order to have as much usable screen as possible).

`Localization` and `Target membership` sections (for particular files) should be moved somewhere else, the UI for .xib editing revamped, and `Utilities` pane rid of.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to do this is to create tabs (Command + T). This way you can adjust the panes for each tab. (please see image)[image]

Comment: Can you assign a keyboard shortcut for, say, tab #5 as `CMD` + `5`? The thing is that tabs get unwieldy beyond a certain number; that is, I've always found the Jump Bar (`^` + `5`) faster (especially, with its instant filtering). And the only OOB provided shortcuts are `Select Next/Previous Tab`. Still, I appreciate your suggestion; will probably reevaluate tabs.

Comment: I use 4-5 tabs for .m,.h,.xib/storyboards, debugger etc so in each tab i navigate by clicking on jump bar items.